# Set param default while using strict mode

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

When using powershell with strict mode activated how do I set the default value for a switch? *If I turn off strict mode then the code works.*

```
Set-StrictMode -Version 3.0

Param (
    [switch]$time_cond = $false,
    [switch]$no_stale = $false
)

If ((Test-Path variable:time_cond) -eq $false) {throw 'No var time_cond'}
If ((Test-Path variable:no_stale) -eq $false) {throw 'No var no_stale'}
```

```
PS F:\z0sh\ps\emwin> .\dl_emwin_0_ops_min06.ps1
WriteError: F:\z0sh\ps\emwin\dl_emwin_0_ops_min06.ps1:6
Line |
   6 |      [switch]$time_cond = $false,
     |                            ~~~~~~~
     | Cannot overwrite variable false because it is read-only or constant.

Exception: F:\z0sh\ps\emwin\dl_emwin_0_ops_min06.ps1:10
Line |
  10 |  … (Test-Path variable:time_cond) -eq $false) {throw 'No var time_cond'}
     |                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | No var time_cond
```

## Edit:

Removing the `= $false` fixes the can not overwrite variable error **BUT** now I get a new error when using strict mode. The error says

```
PS F:\z0sh\ps\emwin> .\dl_emwin_0_ops_min06.ps1
InvalidOperation: F:\z0sh\ps\emwin\dl_emwin_0_ops_min06.ps1:6
Line |
   6 |      [switch]$time_cond,
     |              ~~~~~~~~~~
     | The variable '$time_cond' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
```

Answer (score 2):

A switch already defaults to $false if not used. It’s idiomatic that way so people only use it to make the condition true. If you want to force the user to make a choice, use a mandatory Boolean.